# Web Scraping problem, getting empty list back with BeautifulSoup Library

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to web scraping. I am trying to scrape the genres of a list of movies from their mubi website's source code by their urls. Here I found the genre with classname "css-1wuve65 eyplj6810" in source code shown in the picture below:
[image]

and with the following code, I am trying to get this genre by 'select':
'''

```
for i in range(len(movie_url.movie_url)):
    url = movie_url.movie_url[i]
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.text
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    gener_tags = soup.select('div.css-1wuve65 eyplj6810')
    print(gener_tags)
```

however I keep getting empty list back to every single genre_tags. I have checked url, it is correctly retrieved. Can someone help or give me some tips about how to do this? a sample url is
https://mubi.com/films/elementary-particles

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a dot (`.`) between the `div.css-1wuve65` and `eyplj6810`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://mubi.com/films/elementary-particles'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('div.css-1wuve65.eyplj6810').text)
```

Prints:

```
Comedy, Drama, Romance, Cult
```

Comment: Hi, it is a space between css-1wuve65 and eyplj6810, why are you using dot to connect them?

Comment: @bot99zjc It's how CSS selectors work. `div.css-1wuve65.eyplj6810` means that I want to select `<div>` tag with class `css-1wuve65` AND `eyplj6810` More here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp